# How to perform a MySQL query to format and move data?

Tags: mysql, select, group-by

I currently have a 34,930,054 row MySQL database that is formatted in such a way where entries (previous coder's work) are in multiple rows in a 3 column table, ie:

```
Part number 1 | height | 5cm  
Part number 1 | length | 10cm  
Part number 1 | width  | 5cm   
Part number 2 | length | 1cm  
Part number 2 | height | 3cm  
Part number 2 | width  | 8cm
```

I want to merge the data into a cleaner 2 column table for later output. ie:

```
Part number 1 | height: 5cm  <br /> length: 10cm <br /> width: 5cm  
Part number 2 | height: 1cm  <br /> length: 3cm <br /> width: 8cm
```

How can I do a FIND all rows with SAME part number, INSERT row into new table in the above format of 2 columns (part number in column 1 and all the data from columns 2 and 3 from the original table into column 2 of the new table)?

Comment: what you have done so far!!!

Comment: @diEcho: That's the thing, I don't even know where to start! I don't want to mess it up because otherwise I'll be sitting here waiting for it to go through almost 35m rows to then realise a mistake..

Comment: Advice : dont be scare..start writing.. once you write it and try to learn from ur mistake.

Comment: Thanks. Ok I'm happy to give it a go, is there a resource you can point me to so I can understand a couple of the query commands I will need?

Comment: A word of advice... copy the table and work on the copy. That way, you can mess up as much as you want to.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO parts_new (partnum, description)
SELECT partNum, GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(measurement_type, ' : ', measurement_value) 
              ORDER BY FIELD(measurement_type, 'height', 'length', 'width')  
              SEPARATOR ' <br /> ') description
FROM parts_old
GROUP BY partNum
```

**OR**

```
INSERT INTO parts_new (partnum, width, LENGTH, height)
SELECT partNum, SUM(width) width, SUM(LENGTH) LENGTH, SUM(height) height
FROM (SELECT partNum, IF(measurement_type='width', measurement_value, 0) width, 
        IF(measurement_type='height', measurement_value, 0) height, 
        IF(measurement_type='length', measurement_value, 0) LENGTH
FROM parts_old) AS A
GROUP BY partNum
```

Check the link [**MySQL INSERT INTO...SELECT**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html)

Comment: Thank you @Saharsh Shah - I'm going to give it a go! :)

Comment: +1 I believe your `ORDER BY` statement is out of place, but this is the general idea.

Comment: @macek: Is it? Also, will this just reformat the existing table?

Comment: No I have use Order by keyword to generate 2nd column data in format of Height, Length and Width sequence.

Comment: @Dave, no, this is just a select to show you how to select the data. If you'd like to "save" the result, you could look into a `INSERT INTO my_table (col, col2) (SELECT ...);` type query.

Comment: @macek: could you please show me an example by elaborating on Saharsh Shah's example to do the INSERT? Or Saharsh Shah could you please add the INSERT part? Thank you!!!

Comment: @SaharshShah..could you please tell me what should we do If I want make it into 3 column table like partnumber|height|width.Even have a requirement to do so.

Comment: You can add as many fields as you want add that fields in insert statement and select query also and check the link in my answer

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't know your real table and column names, I'm going to pretend they look like this:

**parts_old (db table)**

```
partnum   measurement_type  measurement_value
-------   ----------------  -----------------
1         width             5
1         length            10
1         height            5
2         width             8
2         length            1
2         height            3
```

If I understand your question correctly, you want to end up with the following:

**parts_new (db table)**

```
partnum   width  length  height
-------   -----  ------  ------
1         5      10      5
2         8      1       3
```

After building the new table with the proper column types, you can migrate the data from the old table to the new table with the following SQL:

```
insert into parts_new (partnum, width, length, height)
(
    select 
        h.partnum as partnum,
        w.measurement_value as width,
        l.measurement_value as length,
        h.measurement_value as height 
    from 
        parts_old as w
    inner join 
        parts_old as l on l.partnum = w.partnum
    inner join
        parts_old as h on h.partnum = w.partnum
    where 
        w.measurement_type = 'width'
        and
        l.measurement_type = 'length'
        and
        h.measurement_type = 'height'    
    group by 
        h.partnum
)
```

I tested this on MySQL 5.1 using Sequel Pro to make sure it works.

Comment: Whoops, actually sorry. parts_new db table should be 2 columns. So the table should have headers "partnum" and "description" and in description, should have: "width: 5<br />length: 10<br />height: 5" combined into the one column

Comment: I know you're working with inherited code, so maybe you don't have the flexibility to change this easily, but the thought of putting visual, HTML tags inside a database table seems like a very brittle approach.  What if you eventually need to query the parts and sort them by width? What if one day you need to display the parts in a PDF document, or a plain text email, or some other visual format that doesn't use HTML tags? Is there a reason you can't separate the visual stuff (the <br /> tags) into the view layer?  (PHP/JSP/ASP/Rails ERB/whatever you're using.)